# Simple Neural Network in Pytorch with 3 inputs (Numerical Values)

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Having a hard time setting up a neural network most of the examples are images. My problem has 3 inputs each of size N X M where N are the samples and M are the features. I have a separate file (CSV) with 1 x N binary target (0,1).

The network i'm trying to configure should have two hidden layers with 100 and 50 neurons, respectively. Sigmoid activation function and cross-entropy to check performance. The result should just be a single probability output.

Please help?

EDIT:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.autograd as autograd 
import torch.nn.functional as F
#from torch.autograd import Variable
import pandas as pd

# Import Data
Input1 = pd.read_csv(r'...')
Input2 = pd.read_csv(r'...')
Input3 = pd.read_csv(r'...')
Target = pd.read_csv(r'...' )

# Convert to Tensor
Input1_tensor = torch.tensor(Input1.to_numpy()).float()
Input2_tensor = torch.tensor(Input2.to_numpy()).float()
Input3_tensor = torch.tensor(Input3.to_numpy()).float()
Target_tensor = torch.tensor(Target.to_numpy()).float()

# Transpose to have signal as columns instead of rows
input1 = Input1_tensor
input2 = Input2_tensor
input3 = Input3_tensor
y = Target_tensor

# Define the model
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_inputs, hidden1_size, hidden2_size, num_classes):
        # Initialize super class
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        #self.criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        
        # Add hidden layer 
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(num_inputs,hidden1_size)
        # Activation
        self.sigmoid = torch.nn.Sigmoid()
        # Add output layer
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(hidden1_size,hidden2_size)
        # Activation
        self.sigmoid2 = torch.nn.Sigmoid()
        self.layer3 = nn.Linear(hidden2_size, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x1, x2, x3):
        # implement the forward pass
     
        in1 = self.layer1(x1)
        in2 = self.layer1(x2)
        in3 = self.layer1(x3)
                      
        xyz = torch.cat((in1,in2,in3),1)

        return xyz
```

```py
# Define loss function
loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# Define optimizer
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-4)

for t in range(num_epochs):

    # Forward pass: Compute predicted y by passing x to the model
    y_pred = model(input1, input2, input3)

    # Compute and print loss
    loss = loss_function(y_pred, y)
    print(t, loss.item())

    # Zero gradients, perform a backward pass, and update the weights.
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    # Calculate gradient using backward pass
    loss.backward()

    # Update model parameters (weights)
    optimizer.step()
```

Here I am getting an error of "
RuntimeError: 0D or 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported"

for line "loss = loss_function(y_pred, y)"

Where y_pred is [20000,375] and y is [20000,1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can refer to [pytorch](https://www.pytorch.org), a python library for deep learning and neural networks.

and you can use code that defines network below:

```py
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

def network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, M):
        # M is the dimension of input feature
        super(network, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(M, 100)
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(100, 50)
        self.out = nn.Linear(50,1)

    def forward(self,x):
        return F.sigmoid(self.out(self.layer2(self.layer1(x))))

----------
```

You can then refer to the [pytorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/pytorch_with_examples.html) and finish the rest training code.

#### Edit:

As for RuntimeError, you can squeeze the target tensor by y.squeeze(). This will remove redundant dimension in your tensor, e.g. [20000,1] -> [20000]

Comment: I have been implementing a code but I am confused on how to implement the 3 numerical inputs because my samples are row vectors with 2000 features but it's very distinctive when there's abnormality in those 2000 features... there will be a large valley and it occurs in the 3 inputs (each one being 1 x 2000). As of right now, I am getting errors because it's expecting 3 inputs and it's getting a large vector. My attempt has been in the forward -- setting it to take 3 inputs and concatenating those 3 inputs into 1. I have edited my post to show the code...

Comment: I am not pretty sure what you want to do now. But if you want to take 3 feature vectors as input to the model, you should concatenate them before feeding it into the layer1 of your model. Forward method in your model should be modified then. Besides, the parameter num_inputs should be set to 6000 right now.